# Measuring temperature at a distance with an infrared sensor - Missing lens?

Tags: sensor

Not sure if this is the ideal stackexchange for this question but I didn't know which other one it should be.

I am trying to measure temperature at a distance via an infrared sensor with a Raspberry Pi. I bought this sensor: [GY-906 MLX90614ESF](https://www.amazon.de/Aihasd-GY-906-MLX90614ESF-Ber%C3%BChrungslose-Temperatur/dp/B017DAPUQS)

The problem with this is that the measured temperature decreases rapidly as the distance to the object increases (after ~10cm I basically only see the surrounding temperature). I suspect that this is due to a missing lens in front of the sensor that would help focus the beam. I have difficulties finding a lens that is appropriate for the sensor.

I tried using a lens that I obtained from taking apart a different (handheld) IR thermometer but it does not work (the measured temperature is more or less that of the lens or rather the construction around the lens). This might not be surprising because this sensor was not made for this lens but I don't know what else to do. I have not found lenses for this purpose online (they need to be transmissive for IR radiation so glass should be out of the question). At this point I'm not sure I am even doing the right thing, and I am wondering why nobody else seems to have this problem.

The question is: Has somebody used an IR sensor before and can tell me what to do here? I would also welcome a suggestion that just recommends a different sensor (maybe one with better documentation) where it is clear what to do.